# MySQL match against not working properly

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `tagline` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_channels_user` (`user_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO 
 `channels` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `tagline`, `created_at`, `image`, `user_id`)
VALUES
 (1, 'sdsd', 'Hello world!', 'dsdsd', '2011-10-09 11:31:59', NULL, 1);


SELECT
  c.id, c.name
FROM channels c
WHERE 
  MATCH(c.description) AGAINST ('Hell' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get 0 results, why?

Comment: Sample code here: http://www.sqlize.com/wpm25nb96q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup @Ben have a point there, stopwords causing this issue

Try read these

Fulltext boolean mode search stopword issue at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19583

Alternative fix for these problem at http://www.nivas.hr/blog/2009/09/15/how-to-disable-mysql-fulltext-stopwords/

Answer (score 0):

The data you inserted does not contain the word 'Hell'.
Try this:

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.name
FROM channels c
WHERE 
  MATCH(c.description) AGAINST ('Hell*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: You probably have the word 'Hello' in your stop word file, which means it will not be indexed. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: Also, try inserting 'Helloes World!'. Then matching against 'Hell*' will work.